# Show that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{2k} +\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{2k-1}$

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following:

> Suppose $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ is absolutely convergent. Show that
>   $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{2k} +\sum_{k=1}^\infty
>  a_{2k-1}$.

I think I know how to proof this, except I find it difficult to write down a formal proof.

My idea was:

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_{2k}| \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_{k}|$

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_{2k-1}| \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_{k}|$

So both $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_{2k}|$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_{2k-1}|$ converge absolutly.

This means that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{2k} +\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{2k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{2k} + a_{2k-1} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{k}$.

I think this is enough, but I am unsure.

Would appreciate some help

Comment: I would expect justifications for the statements $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_{2k}| \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k|$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_{2k-1}| \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k|$. Otherwise it is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n a_{2k} +\sum_{k=1}^n a_{2k-1} = \sum_{k=1}^{2n} a_{k}.$$
Take $n\to\infty$ an apply the hypothesis.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? With the hypothesis, you mean: Suppose $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ is absolutely convergent?

Comment: @Johannes, yes. The absolute convergence of the original series implies the absolute convergence (and convergence) of the other two.

Comment: So after saying that the other two sums converge absolutely, I can use your hint as n $\to \infty$?

Comment: @Johannes, a series converges when the sequence of partial sums converges.